# Extract line number as a variable to re-insert it

Tags: line-numbers

In insert-mode, I would like to extract the *current line number* I'm editing in a "variable"/memory/buffer, and to be able to paste it through a remapping.

I know that `:echo line(".")` gives me the line number. 
I have found how to insert the line number at the beginning of each line, using `:s/^/\=line(".")`.
But I would like to have a remapping like :

```
:inoremap \l <Esc>:echo line(".") > buffer<CR> p
```

that would extract the line number and paste it at my current cursor position.

(Sources of previous searches :
[How to add permanent line numbers to a file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/688/how-to-add-permanent-line-numbers-to-a-file))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for the expression register:

```
inoremap <key> <C-r>=line(".")<CR>
```

or:

```
inoremap <expr> <key> line(".")
```

See `:help \=`, `:help i_ctrl-r`, and `:help <expr>`.

Comment: Is there a way to save this (without having to use `let`) ?

Comment: No. `:let` it is. But you can save it into a variable (`:let foo = ...`) or into a register (`:let @a = ...`).

Answer (score 4):

You can save it in a register with `let` :

```
inoremap \l <Esc>:let @l = line(".")<CR>
```

If you want to immediately paste it, you can do so with:

```
inoremap \p <Esc>:let @l = line(".")<CR>"lp
```