# How to convert a sequence of words to a list?

Tags: formatting

I have the following strings (whitespace and line wise separated) in a file

```
mks asksö askndl
ebre nakkl sadj
```

and would like to have it formatted as follows

```
["mks", "asksö", "askndl"],
["ebre", "nakkl", "sadj"],
```

What shortcut sequence is suitable?

Comment: You could do a substitute to surround the words, and then use global to put in the brackets

Comment: I am fairly new to vim. Could you give me more hints?

Comment: Ill put together an answer later

Comment: `:s` and `:g` are overwhelming a bit right now :) Thx

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways to proceed...

- the simple 2-steps solution

  ```
  :%s/\s\+/', '/g
  :%s/.*/['&'],/
  ```
- or, in one step

  ```
  :%s/.*/\="['".substitute(submatch(0), '\s\+', "', '", 'g')."'],"
  ```
- or also

  ```
  :%s/.*/\=string(split(submatch(0), '\s\+')).','
  ```
- or, my preferred one (in Vim script contexts)

  ```
  :call setline(1, map(getline(1,'$'), 'string(split(v:val, "\\s\\+")).","'))
  ```

And I'm quite sure that macros-oriented-people could VimGolf this *problem* in very few key strokes

Comment: Using `string(split())` is terrific (I was trying to figure out how I could get the output displayed when you `:echo` a list), but--correct me if I'm wrong--doesn't it result in text with single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: Also, I think you're missing the final end-of-line comma in all of these.

Comment: @Rich. You're right, twice. 1. `string(list)` will always produce single quotes, AFAIK. 2. I've forgotten the final comma.

Comment: Also, sometimes ago I had the singular idea of writing my [own stringification function](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/object.vim#L124), but internally I also use `string()` for strings and functions. I could use something else in order to surround with double-quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Since @LucHermitte alluded to a macro-based solution, I thought I'd provide one.

```
qqqqqciw"<C-R>"",<Esc>w@qq@q
qqqqqi]<Esc>I[<Esc><BS>@qq@q
```

First line adds in the quotes and commas, the second line adds the brackets.

*(N.B. in the above, `<C-R>` means press <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>, `<Esc>` means press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and `<BS>` means press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.)*

I could write a long explanation of how this works but honestly, it will be quicker and easier for you just to try typing it in. If you're still not sure what's happening, you might need to read up on [recursive macros](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/691/343) and [`:help i_CTRL-R`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R).

Note that this is not remotely VimGolf'ed. I've no doubt the good people at [vimgolf.com](https://vimgolf.com) could come up with a solution that did the same thing in a quarter of the keystrokes.